CK Editor 5 Custom plugin, custom button
Getting an error during create a custom plugin in ck editor 5.
Here I have added what I have tried so far. This is just basic example that I'm trying.
I want to create a custom plugin to add a predefined templates of html button on toolbar of ckeditor 5 custom button. on click of button table design will add in in ck editor 5 block.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>CKEditor 5 Custom Plugin Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/34.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <style>
    .editor-container {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="editor-container">
    <textarea name="editor" id="editor"></textarea>
  </div>

  <script>
    // Custom plugin definition
    class CustomPlugin {
      constructor(editor) {
        this.editor = editor;
      }

      init() {
        const editor = this.editor;

        const button = editor.ui.componentFactory.add('timestampButton', locale => {
          const button = editor.ui.componentFactory.create('button', {
            label: locale.t('Insert Timestamp'),
            icon: 'clock', // Assuming you're using Font Awesome icons (optional)
            title: 'Insert current timestamp',
          });

          // Handle the button click event (optional)
          button.on('click', () => {
            const now = new Date();
            const formattedDate = now.toLocaleString();

            editor.model.change(writer => {
              const timestampElement = writer.createElement('paragraph');
              writer.insertText(formattedDate, timestampElement);
              editor.model.insertContent(timestampElement);
            });
          });

          return button;
        });

        // Handle the button click event (optional)

      }
    }

    // Initialize CKEditor 5
    ClassicEditor
      .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
        plugins: [CustomPlugin, 'Heading'], // Include your custom plugin here
        toolbar: ['heading', 'timestampButton'] // Add your custom button to the toolbar
      })
      .then(editor => {
        console.log('Editor was initialized', editor);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.stack);
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>




Hi Hitesh! Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Updated please check

Why did you remove the error all together? Please add the (full) error as text inside hte question
